# Problema com Next, TypeScript e ESLint

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, eslint, prettier

Estou iniciando um projeto com Next, TypeScript, ESLint e Prettier. Após iniciar o projeto, adicionar o TypeScript, ESLint e o Prettier comecei a receber um erro ao qual não consigo achar solução, ja tentei de tudo.

Erro:

> JSX not allowed in files with extension
> '.tsx'eslintreact/jsx-filename-extension

Segue o index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>conteúdo</h1>
      </main>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

O eslint.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "prettier/airbnb",
        "prettier/react"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "space-before-function-paren": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off"
    }
}
```

O eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ]
}
```

O prettier.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    semi: true,
    singleQuote: true,
    arrowParens: 'avoid',
    endOfLine: 'auto'
}
```

O package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.3",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Relacionada no [SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614983/jsx-not-allowed-in-files-with-extension-tsxeslintreact-jsx-filename-extensio)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, provavelmente será necessário adicionar esta regra ao seu `.eslintrc.json`

```
rules:  {
  'react/jsx-filename-extension': [2, { 'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
},
```

Vou deixar alguns links de referência para ajudar

- [A mesma pergunta só que no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614983/jsx-not-allowed-in-files-with-extension-tsxeslintreact-jsx-filename-extensio)
- [Informações sobre a regra jsx-filename-extension](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md)
- [Um exemplo de Next com TS, Eslint e Prettier](https://github.com/vczb/boilerplate)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031126/jsx-not-allowed-in-files-with-extension-js-with-eslint-config-airbnb), eu sugeriria colocar isso aqui no **.eslintrc**:

```
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions":[".js", ".jsx"] }],
 }
```